# Cast map structure to void pointer and dereference

Tags: c++, dictionary, casting, void-pointers, dereference

I have been trying to cast a map structure to a void pointer and cast it vice versa.

```
void addToMap(void *data){
// add some elements to the map
}

map<string, vector<myStruct> > myMap;
addToMap(&myMap);
```

I am trying to send myMap to addToMap function as an argument and add some elements inside the function. How can I deference the void parameter back to the map structure ?

I know that static_cast can be used to dereference the void type to know types. For instance:

```
int* a = new int();
void* b = static_cast<void*>(a);
int* c = static_cast<int*>(b);
```

The above snippet would work, but not in this case I suppose. I have already tried it out for my case, perhaps there has to be another trick.

Comment: This is not C, perhaps C++?

Comment: I am building a project in C++ but, there are some C libraries that I use, and the function which takes a void parameter is from these libraries.

Comment: Can't you simply cast it back to your map's type?

Comment: Please use the tag for the language you are writing in (the language the question is actually about and answers should be written in).  The language of any libraries you might happen to be using is probably largely irrelevant.  Also, please expand on "would not work".  Is it a compiler error, a run time error, are missiles being launched?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addToMap function you *can* cast the void pointer back to the original type:

```
void addToMap(void *data){
    auto pmap = static_cast<map<string, vector<myStruct> >*>(data);
    pmap->insert(...);
}
```

> static_cast is also able to perform all conversions allowed implicitly
>   (not only those with pointers to classes), and is also able to perform
>   the opposite of these. It can:
>
> Convert from void* to any pointer type. In this case, it guarantees that if the void* value was obtained by converting from
>   that same pointer type, the resulting pointer value is the same.

Comment: Error: ‘pmap’ does not name a type. Tried to compile with Eclipse on Ubuntu.

Comment: @serhatg this code is valid. Which compiler are you using ?

Comment: @Quentin Previously I have used Cross g++, and I just tried it with GNU g++ 4.6.3. The same error resists.

Comment: @serhatg You should mention that you're using a C++03 compiler in your question. Replace `auto` by the explicit type of the pointer :)